# How I add iOS simulators in android Studio Linux

Tags: ios, linux, android-studio, flutter, ios-simulator

I am writing a simple flutter app on Linux(ubuntu 20.04) using Android Studio(4.1.1). I am able to test my app on android emulators well. Could I know there is any feasibility to test my flutter application in an iOS simulator without moving to mac or connect an iOS device?

Comment: its a universal truth, you cant do apple development anything other than a Apple Mac

Comment: Yes. I got it but I searching for their is any tricks for do that.

Comment: this is your best bet https://hackintosh.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need the mac to compile on IOS devices or use emulators, the project even running on android stuido uses the xcode compiler.

Comment: Thank you. I searching for their is any tricks for do that.